# Linear fit constrained to go through the first point in Python

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, scipy-optimize

I have two `numpy` 1-d arrays of equal length, `x` and a response variable `y`. I'd like to do a least-squares fit that forces the resulting line to go through the point `(x_0, y_0)`. What's the easiest way to pull this off?

Note: some optimization solutions have been proposed. These are good in theory, but the line must go exactly through the point – even if the fit for the rest of the points is worse.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to do a polynomial fit with fixed points](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15191088/1092820) with degree=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do it would be to center your data on (x_0, y_0), run linear regression (specifying no intercept), and then transform the predictions back to the original scale.

Here's an example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.random.randn(100)
y = np.random.randn(100)  +  x

plt.plot(x, y, "o")
plt.plot(x[0], y[0], "o") # x_0, y_0 is the orange dot
```

[image: input data]

Next, use linear regression without an intercept to fit a line that goes through the transformed data.

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

lm = LinearRegression(fit_intercept = False)

# center data on x_0, y_0
y2 = y - y[0]
x2 = x - x[0]

# fit model
lm.fit(x2.reshape(-1, 1), y2)
```

Last, predict the line and plot it back on the original scale

```
# predict line
preds = lm.predict(np.arange(-5, 5, 0.1).reshape(-1,1))
# plot on original scale
plt.plot(x, y, "o")
plt.plot(x[0], y[0], "o")
# add x_0 and y_0 back to the predictions
plt.plot(np.arange(-5, 5, 0.1) + x[0], preds  + y[0])
```

[image]